# Forcing DHCP requests to use a specified server on Debian "Bookworm"

Tags: networking, dhcp

Somebody has accidentally added a rogue DHCP server to his premises network on which I also have machines. He thinks this is probably a WiFi Access Point which he set up to support some new low-budget security cameras.

We've just had a powercut, which has had the result that several computers have got unexpected IP addresses and can't see systems they'd expect to see.

I've told him to temporarily pull the new AP, but in the interim and considering only my own problem:

Is it possible to tell dhcpcd on Debian Linux to only query a specified DHCP server, by specifying the server's MAC or static IP address?

Unfortunately Google et al. aren't very much help here, since almost all prior questions relate to forcing a static client address rather than only using a specified server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of Nmap or associated scripts appear to have an enhancement which improves their ability to report all visible DHCP servers using

> nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover

I was then able to edit a desktop system's /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf to reject advances from the "correct" DHCP server, thus putting a system on the "interloper" server:

> reject 192.168.0.0/24;

Nmap then showed me that the interloper was a Buffalo AirStation which for some reason has come back to life. Until it's located and disconnected "with prejudice" I can use the same sort of directive to reject its interference.

Hope that helps somebody else.